# Permission denied of file with 777

Tags: php

i'm tring to use php function copy() but appear this error:

```
 Warning: copy(/home/smartsch/public_html/admin/student/photos/1tt) [function.copy]:  
 failed to open stream: Permission denied in 
 /home/schoolzs/public_html/admin/student/fileupload.class on line 137
```

The problem is that folder photos and file inside have all permission 777.I don't understand why happen permission denied!!

Comment: is `1tt` a file or a folder? Show the actual `copy()` call.

Comment: You're not matching the same `/home/*` folder, is this the correct behaviour? Are you sure there are `777` permissions? Try `var_dump(is_writable($file));`

Comment: also is the destination you want to copy it owned by your user and have the proper permission as well?

Comment: In warning the access problem is in /home/smartsch/public_html/admin/student/photos/1tt but I can access by my ftp client only in /home/schoolzs/public_html/admin/student/photos/1tt, I can't see the first url by my ftp client!!

Comment: @StefanoMaglione all route to the file should be writable from server root folder. And what `var_dump(is_writable($file));` showing to you?

Comment: var_dump(is_writable($file)) told me the file is not writable,but i found the problem. The directory /home/smartsch does not exist.This is the problem.